# Is Cypress.io really faster than Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, watir, cypress

It looks like Cypress.io launched a massive marketing campaign and one of their selling points that it is '...Much, much, faster than selenium.'

I wrote a test suite of about 5 tests which go through a list of typical login screen validations.

I've used Watir for the selenium-based tests.
Cypress.io execution time 16 seconds.
Watir execution time 13 seconds.

Has anyone come across any proper speed comparison for these tools?

Comment: Interesting question, but I'm not sure if it's on-topic for SO.  I'd like to see a performance comparison tho...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.